# creating a mask on multilevel dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have the following data frame

```
          Style     Land Code      Assessment_per_living
  0       Cape       1010              94.933749
  1       Cape       1010              95.235000
  2       Cape       1010             109.222000
  3   Colonial       1010              64.175109
  4   Colonial       1010              77.270968
  5       Cape       1011              80.856481
  6       Cape       1011              58.060029
  7   Colonial       1011              45.572414
  8   Colonial       1011              67.856000
  9   Colonial       1011              79.564000
  10     Ranch       1011              52.769231
  11     Ranch       1011              57.810434
  12     Ranch       1011              52.472952
  13  Colonial       1012             107.820248
  14  Colonial       1012              84.827050
  15  Colonial       1012              63.626108
  16  Colonial       1012              51.931994
  17     Ranch       1012             109.641711
  18     Ranch       1012              88.243000
  19     Ranch       1012              74.783000
```

I was able to do the following groupby

n_hood_cost_count= df.groupby(['Land Code','Style'])['Assessment_per_living'].mean()

Which yielded the following data frame

```
Land Code  Style   
 1010       Cape        99.796916
          Colonial      70.723038
  1011      Cape        69.458255
          Colonial      64.330805
           Ranch        54.350872
  1012    Colonial      77.051350
            Ranch       90.889237
```

I am trying to add a new column that will adhere to the multi-level groupby but return individual item in the Assessment_per_living column that is greater than the average.  So for example the row 2 in the dataframe will be 1 (pass the mask) whereas rows 0 and 1 would not.  I would want to return the results for all the groupby sets (1010/Cape, 1010/Colonial, 1011/Cape, 1011/Colonial, 1010/Ranch, etc.) that are greater than the average and save this in a new dataframe.  Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `means` with same length as `df`, compare with [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
means = df.groupby(['Land Code','Style'])['Assessment_per_living'].transform('mean')
print (means)
0     99.796916
1     99.796916
2     99.796916
3     70.723039
4     70.723039
5     69.458255
6     69.458255
7     64.330805
8     64.330805
9     64.330805
10    54.350872
11    54.350872
12    54.350872
13    77.051350
14    77.051350
15    77.051350
16    77.051350
17    90.889237
18    90.889237
19    90.889237
Name: Assessment_per_living, dtype: float64
```

---

```
mask = df['Assessment_per_living'].gt(means)
df = df[mask]
print (df)
       Style  Land Code  Assessment_per_living
2       Cape       1010             109.222000
4   Colonial       1010              77.270968
5       Cape       1011              80.856481
8   Colonial       1011              67.856000
9   Colonial       1011              79.564000
11     Ranch       1011              57.810434
13  Colonial       1012             107.820248
14  Colonial       1012              84.827050
17     Ranch       1012             109.641711
```

If need only first 2 columns add [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for unique pairs:

```
mask = df['Assessment_per_living'].gt(means)
df = df.loc[mask, ['Style','Land Code']].drop_duplicates()
print (df)
       Style  Land Code
2       Cape       1010
4   Colonial       1010
5       Cape       1011
8   Colonial       1011
11     Ranch       1011
13  Colonial       1012
17     Ranch       1012
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` and then a condition.

```
n_hood_cost_count= df.groupby(['Land Code','Style'])['Assessment_per_living'].mean().reset_index()
df_new = df.merge(n_hood_cost_count,on=['Land Code','Style'],how='outer')
df_new = df[df_new['Assessment_per_living_x']>df_new['Assessment_per_living_y']]
```

Output

```
      Style  Land Code  Assessment_per_living
2       Cape       1010             109.222000
4   Colonial       1010              77.270968
5       Cape       1011              80.856481
8   Colonial       1011              67.856000
9   Colonial       1011              79.564000
11     Ranch       1011              57.810434
13  Colonial       1012             107.820248
14  Colonial       1012              84.827050
17     Ranch       1012             109.641711
```